# In VS, how can i decide the order in which my overloaded methods are displayed

Tags: visual-studio, overloading

How can i decide the order in which my overloaded methods are displayed in visual studio, in the intellisense

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904876/can-visual-studios-c-intellisense-be-given-a-hint-to-display-a-certain-method-o

Answer (score 0):

Not the best answer, but Visual Studio does not let you control that. It has its own sorting and does not allow for the user to choose. for reference:

[Asked here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904876/can-visual-studios-c-intellisense-be-given-a-hint-to-display-a-certain-method-o)

Comment: Thats bad :(. If i have some 5 overloads, i should be able to logically arrange them in a sequence so that intellisense is user friendly. Otherwise, i may have to so bad and forth to identify the parameters i need to pass.